# Saving an iptables configuration permanently

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

How can I save this configuration permanently?

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add that command to a file that gets executed on startup, for example to `/etc/rc.local`. You can also remove the `sudo` prefix then because this file is executed as `root` anyway.

You could also install and use the package `iptables-persistent`:

```
martin@dogmeat ~ % aptitude show iptables-persistent
Package: iptables-persistent             
State: not installed
Version: 0.5.7
Priority: optional
Section: universe/admin
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 62.5 k
Depends: iptables, lsb-base, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Description: boot-time loader for iptables rules
 This package provides a system startup script that restores iptables rules from a configuration file. 

 Since this is aimed at experienced administrators, there is no configuration wizard.
```

According to the [documentation](http://zertrin.org/projects/iptables-persistent/), it reads the rules from `/etc/iptables/rules`.

Comment: The `iptables-persistent` package is the easiest, least-technical method of getting it working, +1 to that answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Using iptables-save and iptables-restore you can save the actual rules to a file like this:

> iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules

You can add in /etc/network/interfaces file this:

> pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

And this line in the same to save before shutdown your machine:

> post-down iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules

Anyway you can find all the info in the [Community Ubuntu Documentations - How to Iptables](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Saving%20iptables)

Comment: I've seen that in the Ubuntu wiki too, but I don't really like that solution. If something screws up your rules during runtime (for example if something flushes the tables), the `iptables-save` will permanently save to borked configuration and then you'll have to fix it manually.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich, I concur that you should not use the auto-save. If you make changes and your existing firewall is what you want to survive, you just have to remember to call `iptables-save`. On my end, I prefer to edit the `iptables.rules` file and add/remove from it. I used the save once a long time ago and since then I just update the existing rules.